# Are Variables Being Passed In This SQL Statement?

Tags: sql, firebird, wireshark

I'm developing an application that pulls information from a Firebird SQL database (accessed via the network) that sits behind an existing application.

To get an idea of what the most commonly used tables are in the application, I've run Wireshark while using the application to capture the SQL statements that are transmitted to the database server when the program is running.

I have no problem viewing what tables are being accessed via the application, however some of the query values passed over the network are not being displayed in the captured SQL packets. Instead these values are replaced with what I assume is a variable of some sort.

Heres a sample query:

```
select * from supp\x0d\x0aWHERE SUPP.ID=? /* BIND_0 */ \x0d\x0a
```

(I am assumming \x0d\x0a is used to denote a newline in the SQL query)

Has anyone any idea how I may be able to view the values associated with BIND_0 or /* BIND_0 */?

Any help is much appreciated.

P.S. The version of Firebird I am using is 1.5 - I understand there are syntactical differences in the SQL used in this version and more recent versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `/* BIND_0 */` is simply a comment (probably generated by the tool that generated the query), the placeholder is the question mark before that. In Firebird statements are - usually - first prepared by sending the query text (with or without placeholders) to the server with operation `op_prepare_statement` = 68 (0x44). The server then returns a description of the bind variables and the datatypes of the result set.

When the query is actually executed, the client will send all bind variables together with the execute request (usually in operation `op_execute` = 63 (0x3F)) in a structure called the XSQLDA.

Comment: Thanks very much for you detailed response @mark. Is it possible to view the contents of the XSQLDA structure? All responses sent from the server to my PC are appearing as malformed packets in Wireshark at the minute. In addition all packets with op_execute == 63 show no data, just op_ececute = 63.

Comment: @slickboy I'd need to double check that, I do know that the Wireshark dissector for Firebird doesn't always work due to changes in the protocol (although `op_execute` should be unchanged afaik).

Comment: @mark...thanks...it'd be great if you'd be able to point me in the direction of a version of Wiresahrk that is compatable with Firebird 1.5. I've already tried Wireshark 1.8.7 but it also fails to work properly.

Comment: @slickboy It looks like Wireshark doesn't decode most actions further than just the operation code. If you look at the raw data, the packet contains more information after the op_execute: that is the parameter data.